# Validate newly created server support the same load

Tags: jmeter

We are creating a new hosted server for one of our APIs on managed containers (Kubernetes) and we're trying to validate that it can handle at least the same amount of traffic load requests.

We've started with one of the APIs, where we would need to handle at least 140k requests per minute, all endpoints combined.

To verify this, I created a simple JMeter test as follows:

```
-Test Plan

---Thread Group Endpoint1

-----HTTP Request -> a GET request with query params for /path1

---Thread Group Endpoint2

-----HTTP Request -> a GET request with query params for /path2
```

For a local test, I used the following setup:

Thread Groups `Endpoint1` and `Endpoint2` are set to `200 threads (users)`, `ramp-up period of 1s`, `loop count = forever` and `duration 60s`.

Using a `Summary Report` listener when running the test gets me a total of ~9300 `# Samples`.

Using this approach, is it safe to just increase the number of threads (users) for the Thread Groups until I reach the desired 140k requests per minute?

Note: I only used JMeter a little before, so I'm aware that the entire approach may be wrong, therefore any suggestions and steering to the right path are more than welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is viable as long as it represents real-life application usage. If it has 2 endpoints with equally/evenly  distributed load - your setup is just fine. If there are more endpoints and some of them are used more than the others - consider defining the workload correspondingly either using different Thread Groups or other distribution mechanism such as [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller)

Increasing the number of threads is also fine, however consider increasing the load **gradually**, to wit [increase ramp-up time](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-the-ultimate-guide) so your test could have:

1. Arrivals phase
2. Time to hold the load
3. Ramp-down phase

This way you will be able to correlate various metrics like increasing response time, throughput, number of errors, etc. with the increasing load. Also you will be able to state what was the number of threads/requests per second when the system reached [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html)/breaking point and does it recover when the load gets back.

Also make sure you're following [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) as 2300/2500 requests per second is not something JMeter can support out of the box and you will need to do some tuning, at least increase [JVM Heap size](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/web.1111/e13814/jvm_tuning.htm) allocated to JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to achieve the desired 140k requests per minute using a single Jmeter Machine, in that case you'll need Distributed Load Testing approach here.

refer: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html

Also keeping the ramp-up period of 1 second will lead to spike and unrealistic load in the system which will not give proper result unless you've pre-warmed your server, you should gradually increase the load as per real/estimated traffic pattern.